# how to show two dialog at the same time?

Tags: android

how to show  two dialog  at the  same time? i donot to use Multiple Select at one dialog,thank you.

Comment: one give a  suggestion ,the other  waiting  like progrssBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own typed of dialog that **LOOKS** like two dialogs, however, you can actually only have **one** at a time

Answer (score 2):

> hello, how to show two dialog at the same time?

You cannot do this, sorry.